# Separate member function from its class

Tags: c++

If have a bunch of classes, all with the same member function:

```
struct A { void f(){} };
struct B { void f(){} };
struct C { void f(){} };
// ...and so on
```

I do not want to add any abstraction through inheritance, but still I want to be able to call `f()` upon all the given objects.

```
int main()
{
    A a; B b; C c;
    call_all(&f, a, b, c); 
}
```

Question is: how can `f` be isolated from the class context in which is defined, so that a `call_all` template function like in the example can be used?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want, but you can create `static` functions if they don't depend on member variables or you can create free functions that you pass an instance of an object to operate on. Is that what you need/want?

Comment: What would be the use case for such behavior? Technically, your question is, in essence, the same as asking if you can pass `B*`, to a function, that has the signature of `void f (A*);`.

Comment: Have a look at `std::function`, eg: `void call(std::function<void()> func) { func(); }` then you can use `std:::bind()`: `int main() { A a; B b; call(std::bind(&A::f, &a)); call(std::bind(&B::f, &b)); }` or lambdas: `int main() { A a; B b; call([&](){ a.f(); }); call([&](){ b.f(); }); }`

Comment: You could pass a templated function to call `f`: `call_all([](const auto& o) { o.f(); }, a, b, c);`

Comment: I'm really curious why you *don't* want to use a pure virtual interface to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Not generic about name `f`, but you can do:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void call_f(Ts& ... ts)
{
    (ts.f(), ...);
}
```

And then

```
A a; B b; C c;
call_f(a, b, c); // a.f(), b.f(), c.f();
```

More generic with lambda:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void call_all(F&& f, Ts&& ... ts)
{
    (f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), ...);
}
```

And then

```
A a; B b; C c;
call_all([](auto& e){ e.f(); }, a, b, c); // a.f(), b.f(), c.f();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to split a member function from its class, so that the same function can be called on another class?

No. You may not call a member function of `A` with an instance of `B` when the classes are not related. The compiler should report that as a compile time error.

It's not clear to me why you want to do that though.

Comment: I have a bunch of classes all defining same member function `f()` like in the example, and I want to call `f()` on all of them, but I do not know how to speficy `f()` alone without specifying the object it belongs to.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108, in that case, you need to use `call(&A::f, a);` and `call(&B::f, b);`. That is certainly possible.

Comment: Sure, but that would be making two calls. If I could isolate `f()` from its own object, I could write something like: `call_all<A,B,C>( &f );`

Comment: @nyarlathotep108, that seems theoretical/abstract to me. If you can present a concrete use case, there might be ways of accomplishing your goal in an elegant way.